# In selenium Webdriver: For windows, we use Sikuli to interact with windows popup, similar way, what is there for Linux?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, sikuli, linux

In selenium Webdriver: For windows, we use Sikuli to interact with the windows popup. In a similar way, what is there for Linux?

Comment: Can you take an example of what you want to do?

Comment: Sikuli works very well on Linux... just not the same dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I think the regular Sikuli works fine under Linux aswell, certainly [SikuliX](http://www.sikulix.com/quickstart/) does:

> SikuliX can be used on systems with
>
> - Windows XP, 7, 8 and 10 (development on Windows 10)
> - Mac OSX 10.10 and    later (development on macOS 10.15)
> - Linux/Unix systems depending on    the availability of the prerequisites
>
> http://www.sikulix.com/quickstart/